# How can i extract Data from a DataProvider in the charting examples of the WSO2 Viskit library

Tags: wso2, data-visualization, google-gadget

I am using the WSO2 Viskit charting library. I am having problem to pull specific data from a dataProvider.
I can get the data using the data providers. I can add a datareceiver to the data provider. I have created a dataFilter and added it to the dataprovider as a datareciever. as shown below code

```
var dataProvider = new Viskit.p.ProviderGETMakeRequest("http://localhost:8087/generator7.php")
var dataFilter2 = new Viskit.f.BasicFilter(["services", "service"], ["@name"],["Service 01"]);
dataProvider.addDataReceiver(dataFilter2);
dataFilter2.addDataReceiver(lineChart);
```

I am using the timing mechanism provided in the example. If i add the linechart or barchart object to the dataFilter i can retrieve data and have it displayed in a barchart or line chart etc.

My question is can I add a variable or an array as the data receiver instead of the dataFilter or chart object. I just want to extract the raw numerical data so that i can display it on the side of the chart as it gets updated.

Or to put it in another way how can i extract the raw data from the datareceivers (registered with the data provider) and have it stored in a variable or array etc.

Umar

Answer (score 0):

The wso2 viskit is deprecated. There are no maintenance releases for some time as well. There is a new project going on in WSO2 to make web development easier. The new web development framework that WSO2 develops is called [WSO2 Jaggery](http://jaggeryjs.org/). This is a server side javascript framework. For the presentation layer, we stick to straight forward charting libraries such as dojo, jquery, etc. The reason for this is wso2 viskit is much harder to use and maintain than the API of these libraries. HTH

Comment: Hi Tharindu,  Thanks for your reply. I just need to find out how to extract the data from a chart and store it in a variable. Ive already used the viskit quite a bit in my project, its going to be difficult to switch to something else at this stage. I know that Nuwan Bandara of WSO2 knows quite a bit about viskit maybe he might know an answer to this.